# Is there a way to make circular hitboxes in java?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to make a simple game, where you just have to hit some circles, and I was wondering if it is possible to make circular hitboxes instead of rectangular.

This code is written in processing 3.5.1 btw...
I've let some of the code out, basically, the code where I set up the main menu.

```
    //Random ellipse position
      int posx = (int)random(100, 1820);
      int posy = (int)random(100, 980);

    //Score count
        int score = 0;

    //Circlesize/Difficulty
          int circlesize = 100;

    //Hitbox
            float hitsize = 50;


    void setup(){
      size(1920,1080);
      background(255);
    } 



void draw(){

    //What do to if the circle is pressed
     if(mousePressed && mouseX >= (posx - hitsize) && mouseX <= (posx + hitsize) && mouseY >= (posy - hitsize) && mouseY <= (posy + hitsize)){

      //Randomize next location for ellipse
         posx = (int)random(100,1820);
         posy = (int)random(100, 980);

      //Make a new ellipse
         background(255);
          fill(255, 0, 0);
           ellipse(posx, posy, circlesize, circlesize);

      //Add a point to score
         score ++;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Hitbox checks for circular or spherical objects is incredibly easy! Simply take the distance from the origin/center of the circle to the interaction, and if that distance is larger than the radius, then it isn't an interaction on that circle. Using euclidian math you don't even have to eliminate your excess squaring

Comment: I'll try it out thanks

Comment: Got it working, thanks for the help Rogue <3

Comment: Not a problem o/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build on what Kevin said, 
 you can use the code `dist(x1, y1, x2, y2) < 50` inside of an if which checks if the first two parameters (x1, y1) are with 50px of x2 and y2.

**An Example:**

```
int buttonX = 200;// the x position of the circle 
int buttonY = 200;// the y position of the circle 

ellipse(buttonX, buttonY,100,100);// the button

// if mouseX and mouseY are inside the radius of the 100px diameter button then it is active
if(dist(mouseX, mouseY, buttonX, buttonY) < 50) {
   // the mouse is inside of the circle
}
```

I hope that his helped, feel free to ask if you have any questions.

Comment: Just fyi, the page I linked does explain exactly how to do this [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection#circle-circle-collision).

Comment: @KevinWorkman Oh my, I should have read the tutorial more closely... I have edited my response accordingly... sorry :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes. You just have to check the distance between the centers of the circles. If that distance is less than the total of both circle's radiuses, then the circles are intersecting.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/collision-detection) is a tutorial on collision detection in Processing.